# jqueryui's autocomplete html position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

As we all know, when listing the result of autocomplete, jqueryui creates the `<ul>` tag before `</body>`.

How can I put it to another position?

For example:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <input />

     <ul class="ui-autocomplete">
        ......
     </ul>

     <div id="footer">
        ......
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could modify or extend the autocomplete widget's code but that could be difficult if you are not an experienced javascript developer. Why exactly would you want to change its position in the DOM? Simply use css positioning to change the layout of the widget (if you are trying to change the look/feel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-appendTo